# CSS3 onclick rotate and scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I created a simple effect that rotates an image on click using CSS and jQuery. So far, so good, but when the image is wider I want to keep it within the parent div (sort of scaling it along with the rotation).

Here's a fiddle to clarify my question: http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/2/ (just click on the image to rotate).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var angle = 90;
    $(document).on("click", "#parent", function() { 
        $("#img").css ({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        });
        angle+=90; 
    });
 
});
```

```css
#parent {
    width:140px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}

#img {
     max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;

 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/nlobCS5Al8s/maxresdefault.jpg" id="img"/>
</div>
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's probably going to be tricky without setting actual values etc, but here's a start -> **http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/3/**

Comment: Thank you, definitely would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add a `scale()` to the `transform`property and calculate the ratio between picture width and height. **See this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/25/

```
    // within the click function
    var ratio = 1,
        $img = $("#img"),
        $parent = $('#parent');

    if (angle === 90 || angle === 270) {
        ratio = $parent.width() / $img.height();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not going to work since I need to have the whole image visible and fit inside the parent div.

Comment: I thought you meant it the other way round. You can then switch the ratio to be $img.height / $parent.width() and it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/26/

Comment: Well, that's ok, but the scaling is sort of too much. Needs to fit from border to border.

Comment: It's not to much, it's the exact calculated ratio. look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with your fiddle and was able to get it working how I think you want it. Basically you need to check if the image is perpendicular and set max-height/wid and account for margin offset and borders.

Also now corrected to fix margin for height>width images

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/23/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var angle = 90;

$(document).on("click", "#parent", function() { 
    var normalOrientation = angle % 180 == 0;
    var w = $('#parent').width();
    var h = $('#parent').height();
    var iw = $('#img').width();
    var ih = $('#img').height();
    var border = parseFloat($('#parent').css('border-top-width').replace(/px/,''));
    var marginTop = border + ((Math.max(iw,ih) - Math.min(iw,ih))/2) - ((h - ih)/2);
    $("#img").css ({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        maxHeight : normalOrientation ? '100%' : w,
        maxWidth : normalOrientation ? '100%' : h,
        marginTop: normalOrientation || ih === iw ? 0 : ih > iw ? 0 - marginTop : marginTop
    });
    angle+=90; 
});

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Two little issues actually - it seems like that it's not adjusting the origin in firefox. The second issue - if I use taller (heigher) image, the calculations for marginTop are not working as excepted - http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/6/

Comment: Here is an update. Got to use negative margin in that case. http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/19/

Comment: Still doesn't work for every image - http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/20/ I'm trying to find a solution as well, but no luck. Thanks again for investing your time on this.

Comment: this should work for all of them. I just realized I was using the wrong dimensions in the margin. http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/23/

Comment: Thank you!! Btw, still some margin issues you can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/24/ I'll be really happy if you can help

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it work for any posible image, I added another element, container, with 2 states

```
#container {
    width: 140px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;  
}

#container.rotated {
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/5/)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the idea is to work with any possible image. Can we somehow make the animation to run smoothly as in my example? Also, as we said, it should work for every possible image, so we need somehow the adjust the origin as well. Here's what happens with taller (heigher) image - https://jsfiddle.net/52pxbfcs/8/

Thanks again!